# How do I write this in mathematical notation?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

It's a rather simple statement to change into mathematical notation, but I wasn't in class to learn mathematical notation.

"California has more municipalities than Maine".

Help? What is mathematical notation?

Comment: This would be a good question to direct to the instructor or a peer in the class - exactly what answer they expect from you depends a lot more on the context of the class than a universal context of mathematics.

Comment: "Mathematical notation" is a vague means of saying it involves numbers and symbols. What specific notation is expected of you really depends on the context. For example, if you were in grade school, I would interpret the statement as follows..... "Let $C$ be the number of municipalities of California, and $M$ the number of municipalities in Maine. Then $C > M$."

Comment: As Milo said though, you should direct this towards someone who was there that day - "mathematical notation" includes a BROAD range of topics depending on your education, the class, the field of mathematics, etc. etc. etc.

Comment: $A>B$, where $A$ denotes the number of municipalities in California and $B$ the number in Maine.  Is this *really* your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

M(S) = { x : x is municipality and x in S }
|M(California)| > |M(Maine)|